Negative lookbehind doesn't seem to work as expected
Suppose the PHP code
/**
 * @since             1.0.0 <--- this shouldn't be matched
 * @package           blah blah blah
 * Version:           1.0.0 <--- this should be matched
 */

/**
 * Fired during plugin activation.
 *
 * This class defines all code necessary to run during the plugin's activation.
 *
 * @since      1.0.0 <--- this shouldn't be matched
 * @package    blah blah
 * @subpackage blah blah
 * @author     blah blah
 */

define( 'PLUGIN_VERSION', '1.0.0' ); // <--- this should be matched

I want to match the 1.0.0 occurrences that are not after the @since string, so I only want to match the second and third ones.
This regex has to work in VS.Code and I searched for this pattern (?<!since)(?:\s*)1\.0\.0 which doesn't seem to work. What am I missing?
https://regex101.com/r/BGtDx6/1

There's whitespace between @since and 1.0.0. Your negative lookbehind is missing the whitespace.

https://regex101.com/r/ka1jjF/1

Sorry, I pasted the wrong regex pattern, and also the regex101 example was the previous version. I updated my answer, which still doesn't work as expected.

Your regex doesn't work as expected because in other files of the plugin there are less number of whitespaces between @since and 1.0.0

Why would the number of spaces change? These look like automatically-generated comments, I'd expect them all to be the same format.

The reason your regexp doesn't work is because \s* doesn't have to match all the spaces. If it matches one less space, the negative lookbehind is avoided, so the pattern matches.

The reason for your previous question can be seen in these two examples: https://prnt.sc/AWPYexqn4aXF and https://prnt.sc/F-hqauuqSjhW

BTW, there's no need to put a group around \s*

So how would this be solved, since there is no fixed width?

I think you could use something with \K to reset. Either \S(?<!since)\s*\K1\.0\.0 or ^(?!.*since\h*(1\.0\.0)).*\K(?1) or (*SKIP)(*F): since\h*(1\.0\.0)(*SKIP)(*F)|(?1)

Maybe this will suffice: since\h*\d(*SKIP)(*F)|1\.0\.0 (at least it's efficient!)

@bobblebubble this doesn't seem to work in VS.Code though!

@JamesB. Oh, I have overlooked that requirement, only saw "php" (these are PCRE/PHP patterns). And you also want to match the white-space, how about e.g. (?<=\S)(?<!since)\s*1\.0\.0

OMG, this is it @bobblebubble Please put your last pattern as a separate answer! It is what I needed and deserves to be up-voted!

@JamesB. Glad that helped!

You can add another lookbehind to only look back where no whitespace is before:
(?<!\s)(?<!since)\s*1\.0\.0

See this demo at regex101
This will prevent the latter lookbehind to succeed where preceded by a whitespace.
If needed you can capture whitespace and reinsert in the replacement string like this.

This was exactly what I needed! Thank you so much for this!

@JamesB. Welcome! I modified my answer from the positive lookbehind (?<=\S) to a negative variant (?<!\s) which could also match 1.0.0 at start of the string.

Because the number of spaces are not known, one way to do it is to negate the since:
^(?im)\s*\*\s*(?!@since)[a-z]+\s*:\s*1\.0\.0

and then using a capture group, 1.0.0 can be matched:
^(?im)\s*\*\s*(?!@since)[a-z]+\s*:\s*(1\.0\.0)


^: means start of the line.
(?im): means insensitive and multiline flags.
\s*: means zero or more spaces.
\*: literal *
(?!@since): excludes the since.
[a-z]+: one or more a to z chars (other chars can be added as well)
(1\.0\.0): is a capture group including 1.0.0 and can be addressed as $1


For using in VS Code environment, the inline flag should be removed:
(?!@since)[\w\s]+:\s*(1\.0\.0)|^\s*\w+\s*\(\s*['"]\s*[^'"]*['"]\s*,\s*['"]\s*([^'"]*)['"]\s*\)\s*;


It seems that you're trying to do a find-replace operation. In that case:

simply match * @since             1.0.0 using a simple regex (@since\s+(1\.0\.0)) and replace it with a unique string such as A0P8x&2%.
Then, simply search for 1.0.0 and make your changes.
Finally, replace A0P8x&2% with * @since             1.0.0.


Why do you have [a-z]+? There are no letters after @since.

It doesn't work: https://regex101.com/r/y8QWW5/1

@Barmar I thought OP wanted to match Version and not since?

@Barmar The multiline flag is off. Fixed that.

I see. That matches the keywords other than since.

@Barmar Maybe, it seems that OP wants to only exclude since. Thanks for addressing the m flag.

But the gist of your solution is to use a negative lookahead at the beginning of the line, rather than a negative lookbehind before the number.

Exactly, it's only @since lines that I want to not be matched.

@Barmar Yes, that's correct.

@JamesB. You can also use something more compact: (?im)(?!@since)[\w\s]+:\s*(1\.0\.0) and your match is in $1.

@123 your answer doesn't seem to work either because it fails to match the last line (the one with the const) https://regex101.com/r/y4sAYi/1 The regex has to match any 1.0.0 occurrence, except for those having @since at some place within the same line!

And also, your pattern doesn't work at all with VS.Code either!

@JamesB. For using in VS code, inline flags can be removed (?!@since)[\w\s]+:\s*(1\.0\.0). Also, define( 'PLUGIN_VERSION', '1.0.0' ); is another regex that can be written and joined to one regex using a pipe. What other test cases do you have? Update your question with all possible test cases.

Sorry @123 your solution isn't appropriate for my case, as I can't easily predict what other occurrence of 1.0.0 may exist in the plugin's files in order to conjoin them all with a pipe. That's why I asked for something that will match any 1.0.0 but those having @since within the same line. If that's not possible, I'll have to manually do the work I need the pattern for.

@JamesB. Well, in that case, simply match * @since             1.0.0 and replace it with a unique string such as A0P8x&2%. Then, simply search for 1.0.0 and make your changes. Then, replace A0P8x&2% with  * @since             1.0.0. You won't need any regex.

@123 this was my first approach, but there are 77 @since 1.0.0 occurrences, but there are 4 different variations in regard to the whitespaces used between since and 1.0.0... 57 use 4 whitespaces, 3 use 5, 16 use 6 and 1 uses 13. That's why I thought it'd be simpler to somehow ignore all 77 occurrences at once, instead of replacing each variation with a different string, then manipulating the remaining legit ones, then reverting the strings to their corresponding variations! It's strange that this has no easy (or not at all) solution with regex!

@JamesB. Your first approach is better. Use @since\s+(1\.0\.0) and replace it with A0P8x&2%, then make your changes for 1.0.0. Finally, replace A0P8x&2% with  @since               (1\.0\.0). The number of spaces won't matter.

This won't work as it will replace all whitespace variations with the same string, and then I won't be able to revert the replacements with the different whitespace count!

@JamesB. Why do you need exact counts of whitespaces? If you really do, use 4 unique strings for your 4 different variations, and make your changes. Otherwise, wait, maybe someone else has a better solution.

@123 because it will break the alignment of the comments, ie: https://prnt.sc/AWPYexqn4aXF and https://prnt.sc/F-hqauuqSjhW
